# Use computer modern fonts in RMarkdown

Tags: css, rstudio, knitr, pandoc, r-markdown

Suppose you want to use computer modern font, as seen in Latex, for a knitr document produced in the latest version of RStudio (Version 0.98.1091).

So you go online and find a [source](http://checkmyworking.com/cm-web-fonts/) and use it in your .css stylesheet you modified from the stylesheet provided by Package Vignettes:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Computer Modern Concrete';
src: url('cmunorm.eot');
src: url('cmunorm.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('cmunorm.woff') format('woff'),
     url('cmunorm.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('cmunorm.svg#cmunorm') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

body {
 background-color: #fff;
 margin: auto;
 max-width: 700px;
 overflow: visible;
 padding-left: 2em;
 padding-right: 2em;
 font-family: 'Computer Modern Concrete';
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 1.10;
}
```

And call the stylesheet in the YAML:

```
---
title: "CSS for dummies"
author: "This idiot"
date: "December 2014"
output: 
  html_document:
  theme: null
  highlight: null
  css: custom2.css
---
```

The .css stylesheet loaded fine before the new font call, but now you get an error:

```
pandoc: Could not find data file ./cmunorm.eot
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 97
Execution halted
```

The file is clearly there in github.  You search online for hours without relief.  So you come to StackOverflow with what is surely a silly question and brace yourself for a bruising.

Does anyone know where I am going wrong? Huge thanks.

Comment: What operating system are you on? Do you have the same problem when setting `self_contained: no` on `html_document`?

Comment: Mac OS X 10.8.  setting `self_contained: no` allowed the document to compile, but the fonts did not appear.  Still at a loss what to do.

Comment: Where is the `cmunorm.eot` file in relation to the document?

Comment: Downloaded. The css file is in the same folder.

Comment: This probably won't  fix your problem, but I think theme, highlight, and css should be indented one more level in your YAML.